# Python Pandas groupby and mutate a new column with group wise calculations ala dplyr

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am fairly familiar with R dplyr for data analysis and I am trying to convert some of the code I have written in dplyr to pandas. I have data that has a person identified by the ID column and DATE on which that person used a certain PRODUCT. I am trying to figure out the best way to convert the following R dplyr code to python pandas code. Basically, I group by the ID column, filter for a certain type of product, and then add a column that (for each row in the group) adds a minimum (first used) date  and a maximum (last used) date for that person and product. Finally, I also add a column that calculates the number of days between the last used and first used date. Here is the data:

```
ID  PRODUCT DATE
A   ITEM1   1/30/15
B   ITEM1   2/23/14
A   ITEM2   3/22/15
C   ITEM1   1/23/12
B   ITEM1   4/12/15
A   ITEM3   2/2/14
C   ITEM1   1/1/17
A   ITEM1   2/20/15
A   ITEM1   5/18/15
```

using dplyr I can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
mutate(DATE = mdy(DATE)) %>% 
group_by(ID) %>% 
filter(PRODUCT == "Item1") %>% 
mutate(FIRST = min(DATE), LAST = max(DATE), DAYS = LAST - FIRST)
```

which gives me

```
      ID PRODUCT       DATE      FIRST       LAST      DAYS
  (fctr)  (fctr)     (time)     (time)     (time)    (dfft)
1      A   ITEM1 2015-01-30 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
2      B   ITEM1 2014-02-23 2014-02-23 2015-04-12  413 days
3      C   ITEM1 2012-01-23 2012-01-23 2017-01-01 1805 days
4      B   ITEM1 2015-04-12 2014-02-23 2015-04-12  413 days
5      C   ITEM1 2017-01-01 2012-01-23 2017-01-01 1805 days
6      A   ITEM1 2015-02-20 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
7      A   ITEM1 2015-05-18 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
               PRODUCT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("ITEM1", "ITEM2", "ITEM3"), class = "factor"), 
               DATE = structure(c(3L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 9L), 
                                .Label = c("1/1/17", "1/23/12", "1/30/15", "2/2/14", "2/20/15", "2/23/14", "3/22/15", "4/12/15", "5/18/15"), 
                                class = "factor")), 
               .Names = c("ID", "PRODUCT", "DATE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

How can I do the same in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `agg` + `groupby`

```
funcs = dict(FIRST='min', LAST='max', DAYS=np.ptp)
d1 = df.join(df.groupby(['ID', 'PRODUCT']).DATE.agg(funcs), on=['ID', 'PRODUCT'])
```

[image]

Comment: How about the 'transform' function ?

Comment: @Wen what about the `transform` function?

Comment: @piRSquared Something like df['SUM']=df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(sum), But I Do not know  whether this function can add multiple outcome in one time .

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to translate your R code into python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, as_date, group_by, mutate, min, max, filter
[2021-06-24 13:44:46][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "min" has been overriden by datar.
[2021-06-24 13:44:46][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "max" has been overriden by datar.
[2021-06-24 13:44:46][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "filter" has been overriden by datar.
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.ID,  f.PRODUCT, f.DATE,
...     "A",   "ITEM1",   "1/30/15",
...     "B",   "ITEM1",   "2/23/14",
...     "A",   "ITEM2",   "3/22/15",
...     "C",   "ITEM1",   "1/23/12",
...     "B",   "ITEM1",   "4/12/15",
...     "A",   "ITEM3",   "2/2/14",
...     "C",   "ITEM1",   "1/1/17",
...     "A",   "ITEM1",   "2/20/15",
...     "A",   "ITEM1",   "5/18/15",
... )
>>> df
        ID  PRODUCT     DATE
  <object> <object> <object>
0        A    ITEM1  1/30/15
1        B    ITEM1  2/23/14
2        A    ITEM2  3/22/15
3        C    ITEM1  1/23/12
4        B    ITEM1  4/12/15
5        A    ITEM3   2/2/14
6        C    ITEM1   1/1/17
7        A    ITEM1  2/20/15
8        A    ITEM1  5/18/15
>>> df >> mutate(
...     DATE=as_date(f.DATE, "%m/%d/%y")
... ) >> group_by(
...     f.ID
... ) >> filter(
...     f.PRODUCT == "ITEM1"
... ) >> mutate(
...     FIRST=min(f.DATE), 
...     LAST=max(f.DATE), 
...     DAYS=f.LAST - f.FIRST
... )
        ID  PRODUCT        DATE       FIRST        LAST              DAYS
  <object> <object>    <object>    <object>    <object> <timedelta64[ns]>
0        A    ITEM1  2015-01-30  2015-01-30  2015-05-18          108 days
1        B    ITEM1  2014-02-23  2014-02-23  2015-04-12          413 days
2        C    ITEM1  2012-01-23  2012-01-23  2017-01-01         1805 days
3        B    ITEM1  2015-04-12  2014-02-23  2015-04-12          413 days
4        C    ITEM1  2017-01-01  2012-01-23  2017-01-01         1805 days
5        A    ITEM1  2015-02-20  2015-01-30  2015-05-18          108 days
6        A    ITEM1  2015-05-18  2015-01-30  2015-05-18          108 days

[Groups: ID (n=3)]
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using the `transform` function, in conjunction with `assign`:

```py
(df.loc[df.PRODUCT == 'ITEM1']
   .assign(first = lambda df: df.groupby('ID').DATE.transform('min'), 
           last  = lambda df: df.groupby('ID').DATE.transform('max'), 
           days  = lambda df: df['last'] - df['first'])
) 
  ID PRODUCT       DATE      first       last      days
0  A   ITEM1 2015-01-30 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
1  B   ITEM1 2014-02-23 2014-02-23 2015-04-12  413 days
3  C   ITEM1 2012-01-23 2012-01-23 2017-01-01 1805 days
4  B   ITEM1 2015-04-12 2014-02-23 2015-04-12  413 days
6  C   ITEM1 2017-01-01 2012-01-23 2017-01-01 1805 days
7  A   ITEM1 2015-02-20 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
8  A   ITEM1 2015-05-18 2015-01-30 2015-05-18  108 days
```